# Catenary Noetherian commutative rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

> A commutative ring $R$ is catenary if for any pair of prime ideals $p\subset q$, any two strictly increasing chain $p=p_0 ⊂p_1 ... ⊂p_n= q$ of prime ideals
>   are contained in maximal strictly increasing chains from p to q of the same (finite) length.

It is well kown that almost every Noetherian commutative ring with 1 is catenary. For example, clearly, every zero-dimensional (Noetherian) ring is catenary. Is every one-dimensional semilocal Noetherian ring catenary?

Comment: Do you mean universally catenary? Maybe I'm missing something but a 1 dimensional ring should automatically be catenary. A pair of primes is already the maximal chain.